# listar datos con JSON

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, json

hola estoy tratando de listar desde la base de datos por medio de json y extrae todos los datos que están relacionados entre si, pero ala hora de listarlos no logra a mandar todos si no solo uno, pienso que podría ser que solo tome el ultimo como valué y los demás no ya que en consola lo muestra de esa manera. les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```
var detalles = []; 
   function agregarDetalleB(id_Dproducto,materiales,estado){
            $.ajax({
          url:"../ajax/Dproducto.php?op=buscar_DproductoB",
           type:"POST",
          data:{id_Dproducto:id_Dproducto,materiales:materiales,estado:estado},
          async: true,         
          success:function(data){
            console.log(data);            
            info = $.parseJSON(data);           
            console.table(info);           
            listarDetallesB();
            $('#modalDproducto').modal("hide");                         
          }  
        });  
      }
```

desde aca extrae los datos

```
case "buscar_DproductoB";
  $data=$Dproducto->get_DproductoP($_POST["id_Dproducto"], $_POST["estado"]);
   if(is_array($data)==true and count($data)>0){
        foreach($data as $row)
        {
           $data["id_Dproducto"] = $row["id_Dproducto"];
          $data["id_Mprima"] = $row["id_Mprima"];
          $data["materiales"] = $row["materiales"];
          $data["unidadm"] = $row["unidadm"];
          $data["cantidad"] = $row["cantidad"];
          $data["moneda"] = $row["moneda"];
          $data["precio"] = $row["precio"];
          $data["estado"] = $row["estado"];
        }
        } else {
                 $data["error"]="La formula está inactiva, intenta con otro";
          }
    echo json_encode($data);
```

y esta parte es la de sql

```
public function get_DproductoP($id_Dproducto,$estado){
          $conectar= parent::conexion();
          $estado=1;
          $sql="select          p.id_Dproducto,p.numero_Dproducto,c.id_Mprima,c.materiales,c.unidadm,c.moneda,
          c.precio,c.cantidad,c.estado
          FROM Dproducto p
          INNER JOIN detalle_Dproducto c ON c.numero_Dproducto = p.numero_Dproducto
          where p.id_Dproducto=? and c.estado=?
          ";
          $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
          $sql->bindValue(1, $id_Dproducto);
            $sql->bindValue(2, $estado);
          $sql->execute();
          return $resultado= $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
```

aca les dejo lo que me muestra en consola
[image: consola]

esta parta trato de recorrer la matriz

```
for (var i = 0; i <data.length; i++) { console.log(data[i]);   
            var obj = {
              Nbatida : 1,
              codDD  : id_Dproducto, 
              codDpro   : data[i].id_Mprima,
              materiales : data[i].materiales,
              unidadm  : data[i].unidadm,
              precio   : data[i].precio,
              cantidad : data[i].cantidad,
              moneda   : data[i].moneda,
              importe  : 0,
              estado   : data[i].estado
              };           
            detalles.push(obj);
```

de esta manera trato de listar

```
 function listarDetallesB(){    
    $('#listMpriBatida').html('');
    var filas = "";
    var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var subtotalFinal = 0;
    var totalFinal = 0;
    for(var i=0; i<detalles.length; i++){
    if( detalles[i].estado == 1 ){
    var importe = detalles[i].importe = detalles[i].Nbatida * detalles[i].cantidad * detalles[i].precio;        
        importe = detalles[i].importe;    
      var filas = filas + "<tr><td>"+(i+1)+
      "</td> <td><input type='number'  class='Nbatida input-group-sm' name='Nbatida[]' id='Nbatida[]' onClick='setNbatida(event, this, "+
      (i)+");' onKeyUp='setNbatida(event, this, "+(i)+");' value='"+detalles[i].Nbatida+
      "'></td><td name='materiales[]'>"+detalles[i].materiales+"</td><td name='unidadm[]'>"+
      detalles[i].unidadm+"</td> <td name='precio[]' id='precio[]'>"+
      detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].precio+"</td> <td> <span name='cantidad[]' id='cantidad"+i+
      "'> "+detalles[i].cantidad+"</span> </td> <td> <span name='importe[]' id='importe"+i+
      "'>"+detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].importe+
       "</span> </td><td>  <button href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' role='button' onClick='eliminarBa(event, "+
       (i)+");' aria-pressed='true'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> </button></td> </tr>";
      subtotal = subtotal + importe;
            subtotalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+subtotal;
      var su = subtotal;
            var or=parseFloat(su);
            var total= Math.round(or+subtotal);
            totalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+total;
    }
  }
  $('#listMpriBatida').html(filas);
  $('#subtotal').html(subtotalFinal);
  $('#subtotal_Batida').html(subtotalFinal);
  $('#total').html(totalFinal);
  $('#total_Batida').html(totalFinal);
  }
```

Comment: Hola. ¿A que te refieres con listar? ¿Cuál es la salida que estás buscando?, el comando  `$data=$Dproducto->get_DproductoP($_POST["id_Dproducto"], $_POST["estado"]);` ya te está devolviendo la respuesta con una estructura de tabla que puedes recorrer, además de eso el for solo está actualizando los datos de tus indices en $data hasta la ultima vuelta, pero no acumula los registros.

Comment: Aparte de la observación de @AbrahamChan, no incluiste en la pregunta el código de la función `listarDetallesB`.

Comment: aun no he incluido la funcion de  listarDetallesB por que cuando se muestran, solo se ve uno, por ello pienso que estoy mandado mal o no en formato Json

Comment: el comando $data=$Dproducto->get_DproductoP($_POST["id_Dproducto"], $_POST["estado"]); si envia todos los datos, que deseo pero ala hora de hacer el parseJSON pasa  a ser solo un dato el que manda a mostrar

Comment: La salida de la consola con el parseJSON  te da `{"0":{"id_producto":"21",...},"1":{"id_producto":"21",...}}` lo que puede verse es que está devolviendo los dos registros relacionados a tu producto _(el vinagre y el verde liq)_ en un arreglo que puedes recorrer, por lo que el for que tienes antes de hacer el _json_encode_ está de más. Ahora, para justificar el for, solo estás descartando el campo `p.numero_Dproducto`, eso puedes no incluirlo en tu select y también ahorras el for o acumulas la respuesta del for en un arreglo, por eso pregunto ¿Cuál es la salida que estás buscando?

Comment: luego de esta parte {"0":{"id_producto":"21",...},"1":{"id_producto":"21",...}} fuera de los dos areglos muestra el ultimo dato en este caso verde liquido y este lo toma como value y es el unico que me muestra, y lo que estoy 
 tratando es que me muestre los dos pero no se si el problema sea ala hora de recorrer los datos o si el json  extrae no correctamente los datos

Comment: Lo que está comentando @AbrahamChan es para que recibas un arreglo de objetos, en lugar de un objeto con más objetos dentro. El código de la función para listar es necesario, de otra forma va a ser muy difícil encontrar el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es que el método `$Dproducto->get_DproductoP()` ya te está devolviendo un arreglo con los datos obtenidos de la consulta, tal como necesitas, y no debes modificarlo. Te sugiero que lo que vas a devolver incluya una propiedad `error`, que te permita detectar si se encontraron resultados o no:

```
case "buscar_DproductoB";
    // Define un arreglo para devolver correctamente la información
    $data = ['error' => '', 'datos' => []];
    // Actualiza la propiedad "datos"
    $data['datos'] = $Dproducto->get_DproductoP($_POST["id_Dproducto"], $_POST["estado"]);
    // Si no hay resultados, marcar como error
    if(!is_array($data['datos']) || count($data['datos']) == 0) {
        $data["error"] = 'La formula está inactiva, intenta con otro';
    }
    // Devuelve un objeto con dos propiedades:
    // error = cadena vacía o mensaje de error
    // datos = arreglo vacío o datos obtenidos de la consulta
    echo json_encode($data);
```

El resultado será algo como:

```
{
    error: '',
    datos: [
        {id_Dproducto: 1, id_Mprima: x, ... },
        {id_Dproducto: 2, id_Mprima: x, ... },
    ]
}
```

Ahora hay que definir la el arreglo `detalles` en contexto global (fuera de funciones) y analizar el resultado en la respuesta AJAX:

```
// Definir arreglo
let detalles = []

// Petición AJAX
function agregarDetalleB(id_Dproducto,materiales,estado) {
    // Borrar datos anteriores, si es que los hay
    detalles = [];

    $.ajax({
        url:"../ajax/Dproducto.php?op=buscar_DproductoB",
        type:"POST",
        data:{id_Dproducto:id_Dproducto,materiales:materiales,estado:estado},
        dataType: 'json', // jQuery convertirá la respuesta en JSON
        async: true,         
        success:function(data){
            // Solo para comprobar los datos recibidos
            console.log(data);
            // Hubo error?
            if(data.error != '') {
                alert(data.error);
            } else {
                // Asignar datos recibidos a arreglo
                detalles = data.datos;
                // Crear listado
                listarDetallesB();
            }
            $('#modalDproducto').modal("hide");
        }  
    });  
}
```

Finalmente, tu función para listar datos, usa la variable global `detalles`:

```
function listarDetallesB() {
    $('#listMpriBatida').html('');
    var filas = "";
    var subtotal = 0;
    var total = 0;
    var subtotalFinal = 0;
    var totalFinal = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < detalles.length; i++) {
        // Si no hay valor en Nbatida
        if(typeof detalles[i].Nbatida == 'undefined' || !detalles[i].Nbatida) {
            // Inicializar en 1
            detalles[i].Nbatida = 1;
        }
        if( detalles[i].estado == 1 ) {
            var importe = detalles[i].importe = detalles[i].Nbatida * detalles[i].cantidad * detalles[i].precio;        
            importe = detalles[i].importe;    
            var filas = filas + "<tr><td>"+(i+1)+
                "</td> <td><input type='number'  class='Nbatida input-group-sm' name='Nbatida[]' id='Nbatida[]' onClick='setNbatida(event, this, "+
                (i)+");' onKeyUp='setNbatida(event, this, "+(i)+");' value='"+detalles[i].Nbatida+
      "'></td><td name='materiales[]'>"+detalles[i].materiales+"</td><td name='unidadm[]'>"+
            detalles[i].unidadm+"</td> <td name='precio[]' id='precio[]'>"+
            detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].precio+"</td> <td> <span name='cantidad[]' id='cantidad"+i+
      "'> "+detalles[i].cantidad+"</span> </td> <td> <span name='importe[]' id='importe"+i+
      "'>"+detalles[i].moneda+" "+detalles[i].importe+
       "</span> </td><td>  <button href='#' class='btn btn-danger btn-lg' role='button' onClick='eliminarBa(event, "+
       (i)+");' aria-pressed='true'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span> </button></td> </tr>";
            subtotal = subtotal + importe;
            subtotalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+subtotal;
            var su = subtotal;
            var or=parseFloat(su);
            var total= Math.round(or+subtotal);
            totalFinal = detalles[i].moneda+" "+total;
        }
    }
    $('#listMpriBatida').html(filas);
    $('#subtotal').html(subtotalFinal);
    $('#subtotal_Batida').html(subtotalFinal);
    $('#total').html(totalFinal);
    $('#total_Batida').html(totalFinal);
}
```

No revisé la función completa, pero el ciclo ya debe funcionar sin problema porque ahora sí recibes un arreglo para recorrer.

Comment: GRACIAS AMIGO, EN SERIO GRACIAS.

Comment: trate de hacerlo durante una semana o mas y no pude. eres un genio gracias!!!!!!!

Comment: hola disculpa que te moleste me podrias ayudar.

Comment: en la parte donde se manda listardetallesB(data.datos) en el json quisiera mandar Nbatida=1, para que ala hora de listar ya tenga ese valor esa variable ya que esta no viene desde la base